# How to get 100% GPU usage using CUDA

Tags: cuda

I wonder how I can generate high load in a GPU, step by step, though.
What I'm trying to do is a program which put the maximum load in a MP, then in other, until reach the total number of MP.

It would be similar to execute a "while true" in every single core of a CPU, but I'm not sure if the same paradigm would work on a GPU with CUDA.

Can you help me?

Comment: The answer probably depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want to measure maximum power consumption? Do you want to perform some kind of benchmark? ...?

Comment: Define "maximum load". If this means utilization of execution units, the "while true" approach won't come anywhere close to that on CPU and GPU alike. Besides, there are existing programs for that already.

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to define "GPU usage." If you mean, 100% reported in nvidia-smi, I'd be curious to hear why exactly do you pick that measure (and I'm not even sure what exactly does it reflect). An obvious alternative is to get as close to the TDP as possible, but that can achieved even without 100% "Volatile GPU Utilization" shown by nvidia-smi.

Comment: @ManuelM Yes! My aim is to know the consumption when it their SM (and their cores) are doing computation (such a matrix multiplication). At first glance I thought that a "while true" will work, but probably the compiler is optimising it.

Comment: @pszilard As far as I know, there is no measure to indicate the load computation (as htop would do it) but if I know that what I'm executing is really stressing the consumption measures should be right. Thank you all for your interest!

Comment: What do you mean by "load consumption"? Power consumption? On Tesla and Quadro cards "nvidia-smi" does show it, on GeForce it does not. There is a "fix" for the nvml library to make it "work correctly" but AFAIK it only work with drivers up to 331.xx: https://github.com/CFSworks/nvml_fix

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a stress-test/power consumption test, you'll need to pick the workload. The highest power consumption with compute-only code you'll most likely get with some synthetic benchmark that feed the GPUs with the optimal mix and sequence of operations. Otherwise, BLAS level 3 is probably quite close to optimal.

Putting load only on a certain number of multi-processors will require that you tweak the workload to limit the block-level parallelism.

Briefly, this is what I'd do:

- Pick a code that is well-optimized and known to utilize the GPU to a great extent (high IPC, high power consumption, etc.). Have a look around on the CUDA developer forums, you should be able to find hand-tuned BLAS code or something alike.
- Change the code to force it to run on a given number of multi-processors. This will require that you tune the number of blocks and threads to produce exactly the right amount of load for the number of processors you want to utilize.
- Profile: the profiler counters can show you the amount of instruction per multi-processor which gives you a check that you are indeed only running on the desired number of processors as well as other counters that can indicate how efficiently is the code running.
  as well as
- Measure. If you have a Tesla or Quadro you get power consumption out of the box. Otherwise, try the [nvml fix](https://github.com/CFSworks/nvml_fix). Without a power measurement it will be hard for you to know how far are you from the TDP and especially weather the GPU is throttling.

Answer (score -1):

Some of my benchmarks carry out the same calculations via CUDA, OpenMP and programmed multithreading. The arithmetic operations executed are of the form x[i] = (x[i] + a) * b - (x[i] + c) * d + (x[i] + e) * f with 2, 8 or 32 adds or subtracts and multiplies on each data element. A range of data sizes are also used. [Free] Benchmarks, source codes and results for Linux are via my page:

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/linux%20benchmarks.htm

I also provide Windows varieties. Following are some CUDA results, showing maximum speed of 412 GFLOPS using a GeForce GTX 650. On the quad core/8 thread Core i7, OpenMP produced up to  91 GFLOPS and multithreading up to 93 GFLOPS using SSE instructions and  178 GFLOPS with AVX 1. See also section on Burn-In and Reliability Apps, where the most demanding CUDA test is run for a period to show temperature gains, at the same time as CPU stress tests.

```
            Core i7 4820K 3.9 GHz Turbo Boost GeForce GTX 650

  Linux CUDA 3.2 x64 32 Bits SP MFLOPS Benchmark 1.4 Tue Dec 30 22:50:52 2014

  CUDA devices found 
  Device 0: GeForce GTX 650  with 2 Processors 16 cores 
  Global Memory 999 MB, Shared Memory/Block 49152 B, Max Threads/Block 1024

  Using 256 Threads

  Test            4 Byte  Ops  Repeat   Seconds   MFLOPS             First  All
                   Words  /Wd  Passes                              Results Same

 Data in & out    100000    2    2500  0.837552      597   0.9295383095741  Yes
 Data out only    100000    2    2500  0.389646     1283   0.9295383095741  Yes
 Calculate only   100000    2    2500  0.085709     5834   0.9295383095741  Yes

 Data in & out   1000000    2     250  0.441478     1133   0.9925497770309  Yes
 Data out only   1000000    2     250  0.229017     2183   0.9925497770309  Yes
 Calculate only  1000000    2     250  0.051727     9666   0.9925497770309  Yes

 Data in & out  10000000    2      25  0.369060     1355   0.9992496371269  Yes
 Data out only  10000000    2      25  0.201172     2485   0.9992496371269  Yes
 Calculate only 10000000    2      25  0.048027    10411   0.9992496371269  Yes

 Data in & out    100000    8    2500  0.708377     2823   0.9571172595024  Yes
 Data out only    100000    8    2500  0.388206     5152   0.9571172595024  Yes
 Calculate only   100000    8    2500  0.092254    21679   0.9571172595024  Yes

 Data in & out   1000000    8     250  0.478644     4178   0.9955183267593  Yes
 Data out only   1000000    8     250  0.231182     8651   0.9955183267593  Yes
 Calculate only  1000000    8     250  0.053854    37138   0.9955183267593  Yes

 Data in & out  10000000    8      25  0.370669     5396   0.9995489120483  Yes
 Data out only  10000000    8      25  0.202392     9882   0.9995489120483  Yes
 Calculate only 10000000    8      25  0.049263    40599   0.9995489120483  Yes

 Data in & out    100000   32    2500  0.725027    11034   0.8902152180672  Yes
 Data out only    100000   32    2500  0.407579    19628   0.8902152180672  Yes
 Calculate only   100000   32    2500  0.113188    70679   0.8902152180672  Yes

 Data in & out   1000000   32     250  0.497855    16069   0.9880878329277  Yes
 Data out only   1000000   32     250  0.261461    30597   0.9880878329277  Yes
 Calculate only  1000000   32     250  0.060132   133042   0.9880878329277  Yes

 Data in & out  10000000   32      25  0.375882    21283   0.9987964630127  Yes
 Data out only  10000000   32      25  0.207640    38528   0.9987964630127  Yes
 Calculate only 10000000   32      25  0.054718   146204   0.9987964630127  Yes

 Extra tests - loop in main CUDA Function

 Calculate      10000000    2      25  0.018107    27613   0.9992496371269  Yes
 Shared Memory  10000000    2      25  0.007775    64308   0.9992496371269  Yes

 Calculate      10000000    8      25  0.025103    79671   0.9995489120483  Yes
 Shared Memory  10000000    8      25  0.008724   229241   0.9995489120483  Yes

 Calculate      10000000   32      25  0.036397   219797   0.9987964630127  Yes
 Shared Memory  10000000   32      25  0.019414   412070   0.9987964630127  Yes
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried your benchmark and I tested over a K20c and this is what I get from your program: 
  `Device 0: Tesla K20c  with 13 Processors 104 cores 
  Using 256 Threads`                                                                                                       And the GPU has 192 cores.                                                                                 Moreover I've seen that only consumes less than a quarter part of nominal power... Shouldn't it consume a quantity similar to the maximum?

Comment: For maximum loading with that program, you should run it just using the Fast Shared Memory Test, like for 10 minutes using command  ./cudamflops32SP Mins 10, FC

Comment: I tried the 64bits version of the program with your configuration, and it's true that the comsuption has boosted until 155W out 225W, a little bit more of half nominal power. Shouldn't be higher? Other question that I have is why this output: `Device 0: Tesla K20c  with 13 Processors 104 cores`. As far as I know, this device has 192... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Program GPU processor count is from early CUDA compiler and is not correct anymore.